# Нужно ли выделять запятыми?

Tags: пунктуация

Ставятся ли запятые - Ей также предложено, в том случае, если квартира является частной собственностью, направить копии док-в в адрес регионального оператора.

Comment: Какая конкретно запятая вас интересует?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Одна из двух первых лишняя, скорее всего - первая. 
Составной союз "в случае если" может целиком входить в придаточную часть, но может и расчленяться, но никак не одновременно. Поэтому две запятые вокруг "в том случае" - явный перебор. Выбор варианта зависит от нескольких факторов, это вопрос больше стилистики.

При этом, однако, если в составной союз входит слово "то" ("в том"), предпочтение обычно отдается расчленению союза. Т. е. корректный вариант будет:

***Ей также предложено в том случае, если квартира является частной собственностью, направить копии док-в в адрес регионального оператора.***

Кстати, мне очень не нравится здесь сокращение слова "документов", зачем оно, что тут выгадывать-то пять символов на сотню?